# Not able to click over icon triangle in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've done a customized select with Jquery. I've put a triangle `FontAwesome` icon floating to the right. The problem is when I try to click in the icon the mouse pointer doesn't let me click. The space occupied by the icon is not able to be clicked. I wonder how could I fix this or if is possible with css.

This is my code

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

```css
.main-search-results:after {
  content: "\f0dd";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  padding-left: 4%;
  border-left: 1px solid $text-color;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-search-results">
  <select name="" id="select-filter-1">
    <option value="default">Cualquier provincia</option>
    <option value="a_coruña">A Coruña</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,

I have created fiddle for you so take a look what I did here..

http://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/jsxuvkn6/

```
.w{
    position:relative;
}
.ui-selectmenu-button::after {
   content: "\f0dd"; 
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   right: 15px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.ui-icon{
    display:none;
}
```

- I attached the FA icon on to generated jqueryUI item..
- removed (display: none) the initial dropdown

I now can click on that triangle,, test it to see if that works for you

hth, k

Comment: oserk what would be 'w' in this case?? This is exatly what i want but I don't know what is 'w'

Comment: I think this fiddle is what you need,, http://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/jsxuvkn6/1/ that w is just as wrapper of that element,, I don't think that is needed anymore, I first thought that is needed to position the element.. hey I can't reproduce your problem,, whole button is clickable right?

Comment: Great answer oserk. it is working perfect right now. I think I needed to remove the z index property. Thanks a lot for your help